# No destination specified for message Nservicebus 2.6 and SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, nservicebus

So I'm trying to send a simple message from a SharePoint webpart to an endpoint.  For now, i'm setting the bus in a simple static class use in the webpart.  The class gets called and the bus seems to be working, but when i try to send the message, i get:

No destination specified for message SharePointMessages.CreateProject. Message cannot be sent. Check the UnicastBusConfig section in your config file and ensure that a MessageEndpointMapping exists for the message type.

The class looks like this:

```
    public static class Infrastructure
{
    public static IBus Bus { get; private set; }
    static Infrastructure()
    {
        var mappings = new MessageEndpointMappingCollection();
        mappings.Add(new MessageEndpointMapping()
                        {
                            Messages = "SharePointMessages.CreateProject",
                            Endpoint = "SharePointProxy"
                        });

        Configure config = Configure.WithWeb();
        config
            .Log4Net()
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .XmlSerializer()
            .MsmqTransport()
            .IsTransactional(true)
            .UnicastBus()
            .Configurer.ConfigureComponent<UnicastBusConfig>(ComponentCallModelEnum.None)
            .ConfigureProperty(x => x.MessageEndpointMappings, mappings);

            Bus = config.CreateBus().Start();

    }

}
```

The SharePointMessages.CreateProject class implements IMessage and has two properties.
The queues get created properly if they are not there.  So it seems like everything is working but for some reason the mappings are not there.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: Try qualifying the name of the type with the name of the assembly. So something like: "SharePointMessages.CreateProject, AssemblyName"

Comment: I still get the same message, I made sure everything is being deployed to the GAC, so all assemblies are in the same place.

Comment: Have you considered upgrading your stack to version 3? Appreciate this does not address your problem directly but 2.6 had some problems with it which have been fixed in 3.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a custom configuration source - http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/message-owner